# PhysicsWorld.setGravity(gravity);

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

[image]

well I am using andengine and box2d extension
you see, my objects flying from ground (red rectange) to roof (yellow one) of my camera, how is that posibble I dont understand

this is a part of my code,

```
@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
    final Camera camera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

    return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.PORTRAIT_FIXED,
            new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), camera);

}
```

and Also this

```
@Override
protected Scene onCreateScene() {

    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    this.mScene = new Scene();
    this.mScene.setBackground(new Background(256, 256, 256));

    this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0,SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH),false);
    this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(this.mPhysicsWorld);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have to use -SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH, like this:

```
this.mPhysicsWorld = new PhysicsWorld(new Vector2(0, -SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH),false);
```

In the AndEngine AnchorCenter Branch you have to use negativ values as gravity, to make your physics objects fall down, because the coordinate system was changed.

Comment: I had the same problem, is it the formal solution?